# What's with Battlemind's Iron Fist being so powerful?

Tags: dnd-4e, battlemind

I'm a bit confused about this one.

Like, almost every melee class have an at-will power that is basically equivalent:

> Main Stat VS AC
>   1[W]+Stat modifier + Stat modifier Temp HP on hit.

Fighters have it, Avengers have it, barbarians, paladins, etcetc. They all have the power that does roughly the same thing, and is balanced and equivalent.

Then, Battlemind happens.

Not only is it a Resistance to all damage and therefore applies to every attack, but it's an effect and therefore applies even on a miss.

Is it just me or it's somewhat gamebreaking for an at-will power?

Basically, hit or miss, he gains that DR. So he can have it almost permanently.

I understand that this power might become weaker as the levels progresses, but so does every "equivalent" power with the temp HP... ?

Comment: Would be good to include the text for Iron Fist, or to explain how it's different than your example power, which is formatted in a confusing way. Didn't know what the question was until I read the answer.

Answer (score 9):

The Resist lasts one turn. THP last until taken away (when hit).

So, given the same value (e.g. 4, which is not game-breaking):

- Resist for one turn is *better* if the character is hit twice.
- THP is *better* if the character is not hit.
- The two buffs are numerically identical if the character is hit just once before the next turn.

It is a more reasonable trade-off than it might seem at first sight.

Also, THP stack with resistances gained from other powers, whilst this relatively weak resist will not. That applies the other way around of course, but there are some nicer Resist-based Utility powers available to the Battlemind that will not stack with this power.

There is a Battlemind PC in my group, we have played from Level 1 to Level 11, and he did not rate the power enough compared to mobility- or mark-based ones to ever take it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not as game-breaking as you might expect.

This is due to Iron Fist using the character's WIS modifier as the amount of DR gained. Because a Battlemind is usually CON primary, unless the character expends points into WIS, but really would be better off putting it into CON, considering most of the Battlemind's powers are CON based (to hit modifier on at-will abilities, HP etc).

The example ability above however gives THP based of the character's main stat, which is going to improve over time, but be lost more easily to an  attack.

For my Level 4 Harrier Battlemind, I'm CON Primary (+5), WIS Secondary (+3). However my AC is 24, so the +3 DR I get if I use Iron Fist is only useful if the enemy actually hits me, which with an AC of 24 doesn't happen often. It does get more useful if you start bringing status effects into play, like poison, because it (partially) negates the DOT that those effects cause.

I personally use Iron Fist when I've got multiple enemies marked that are trying to batter me, so if they do slip past my AC, I don't take quite as much damage as I otherwise would of, but when an Orc crits with his Great Axe, taking 3 damage off of 25 isn't really that useful.

It's a question of do you consider it more useful to have a smaller amount of (fairly constant) damage reduction VS a larger (and probably increasing as you level) amount of THP to keep you alive. Also keep in mind that the Battlemind would have to continually use Iron Fist every turn to keep the DR active, which isn't always going to be the best course of action.